# MyPy: class with dynamically generated class variables always having the same type

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'd like to have a data class that only stores string variables, something like this:

```
class Properties:
   pass


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.properties = Properties()
        properties_json = self.get_properties_json() 
        for key, value in properties_json:
            setattr(self.properties, key, value)

    def get_properties_json(self) -> dict[str, str]:
        ...
```

How can I tell `MyPy` that Properties has dynamic variables that are always `strings`?

Comment: Are you sure it's not ```self.properties = Properties```?

Comment: You are correct, fixed.

Comment: But with ```self.properties = Properties()```, ```self.properties``` is already an instantiated Properties object.  So ```properties_json = self.properties()``` will give you an error.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's been a really long day. I fixed it again, does it work now?

Comment: You could consider using the `typing.cast()` function? if you know it's already going to be the case then I think it'd work well enough. Generally data from getattr and setattr can't be type hinted easily, so I don't think there'd be any better options.

Comment: You want [this](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8203). It is 3 years old feature request with "normal" priority, not implemented. The best thing you can do is to allow arbitrary attribute access on `Properties` with `def __getattr__(self, key: str, /) -> str: ...`, I suppose.